# ListVectorPlot contour lines

Tags: plotting

I dont know why so many plot functions lack the option to display contour lines (judging by the search result for *[plot function] contour lines*) but ListVectorPlot is among them.

If I have an array `t` of `{vx,vy}` coordinates, do you know a way to plot it with overimposed the contour lines?

Comment: As in `ListVectorDensityPlot[]`? It doesn't have lines, but really lines just clutter up such a graph. You might have to superimpose two graphs if you really want the lines themselves.

Comment: Have a look at `MeshFunctions`.

Comment: Two options come to mind, first the [`StreamPoints`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BEn5z.png) option `VectorPlot` and `ListVectorPlot`.  Second, you could just use `Show` to combine different types of 2D plots

Comment: @J.M.: I never used it so probably I made some mistake. I tried this syntax: ListVectorPlot[tt, VectorPoints -> 40, Mesh -> 20,  MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}] and though I get no error, I see no meshes...

Comment: @JasonB: I thought it was a great idea using StreamPoints, until I realized that the streamlines are exactly *perpendicular* to the direction I need, that is the contour line!

Comment: (the vector field I'm using is at http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=33681822192094244768&t=3368182219209424476880849 as a matlab export datafile, if somebody wants to play with it)

Comment: What do you want the contours to be based on, `vx`, `vy`, the vector magnitude `Norm[{vx, vy}]^2`?

Comment: @JasonB: vx or vy, they're both good

Comment: @Feyre: sorry I needed to suffer a bit before discovering that, in ListVectorDensityPlot[], without ColorFunctionScaling -> False,  nothing was shown but an uniform background... yes, it's a first step although I preferred lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `ListVectorPlot` superimposed on top of `ListContourPlot`(s) of the `vx`, `vy`, and magnitudes

```
data = Import["~/Downloads/tt.mat"];
vectorplot = ListVectorPlot[Transpose@data, VectorStyle -> Red];
Show[ListContourPlot[Map[#, data, {2}]], vectorplot, ImageSize -> 400,
    PlotRange -> All] & /@ {First, Last, Norm[#]^2 &}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you can use `MeshFunctions` to get the contour lines out of `ListVectorDensityPlot`

```
ListVectorDensityPlot[Map[#, Transpose@data, {2}], Mesh -> 10, 
   MaxRecursion -> 3, ImageSize -> 400, 
   VectorStyle -> Red] & /@ {{#, First@#} &, {#, Last@#} &, {#, 
    Norm@#} &}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks! I understand better how to do it now...